# Shallow copy of object not correctly updating original object

Tags: java, eclipse, shallow-copy

I would like to model a graph, and to do so :

- I have a class A that contains a LinkedList of instances of A and has a setter method associated :

```
class A {
    private LinkedList<A> list;
    [...]
    public setList(LinkedList<A> l) {
        this.list = l;
    }
}
```

- And in an other class NetA I have a method genCon that takes a LinkedList of instances of A then sets their list attribute to be a shuffled SubList of rlist :

```
static void genCon (LinkedList<A> rlist) {
    for(int i=0; i<rlist.size(); i++) {
        A temp = rlist.get(i);
        LinkedList<A> slist = new LinkedList<A>(rlist.subList(0, rlist.size()));
        temp.setList(slist);
    }
}
```

Then genCon(rlist) is called in main, but altough all the objects of rlist should have their list initialized (and being equal to a shuffled version of rlist) some appear to be empty, with no consistent pattern (i.e. not every n or repeatable pattern), but completely at random.

At first I thought that `A temp = rlist.get(i)` was not giving me a shallow copy of the object at index i, but the check for identity with `==` returns true, so, if I am not mistaken that means that both variable hold the same reference and that should not be what is causing the issue?
Then I thought that it might be an optimization issue, maybe eclispe tries to do the operations in parallel and that somehow messes up the initialization at random?
I have tried to process step by step, but I can't seem to find where I messed up.
What did I miss?

Edit :

The main function looks like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<A> a_list = generateAList(20);
    genCon(a_list);

    for(int i=0; i<a_list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(a_list.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

a_list is correctly initialized. The issue happens in the following loop, when trying to print the objects.
Since it's only for testing main is located in the same class as genCon() atm.

generateAList() looks like this :

```
static public LinkedList<A> generateAList(int n) {
    LinkedList<A> a_list = new LinkedList<A>();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        ap_list.add(A.rand()); // A.rand() is just a static function that return an instance of A with randomly set values and an unitialized list.
    }

    return ap_list;
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see a complete example that reproduces the problem.  Your error is clearly someplace in the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Hello @Balocre, could you please show me the main method as well?

Comment: @markspace Well, it's not a really big project, but still I skipped a good portion of code writing the post, and if I understand StackOverflow guidelines it would not be appropriate for me to post large portion of messy code. But if you are 100% positive there is no error in what posted at leats I know where not to look! I will eventually post a link to the project if I still can't find anything...

Comment: @SergioArrighi I updated the post, it's quite simple really. I don't think the error originates from there.

Comment: Hi @Balocre, yes I see but there are some things I don't understand and I would like to reproduce. Also everything here depends on how you fill your list as it is an iterative structure it may be really complex. Could you also share the generateAList method please?

Comment: @SergioArrighi I updated the post, unfortunately I have to go attend my courses, I will try to update the post and do some formatting when I will be back as I fear this gets a little confusing...

Comment: @Balocre still you are not showing us how you generate the list :D. It is important to know this detail to advice you I think. Have a good time at your courses. Cheers!